# Python - Pybarcode Scanner

Tags: python

```
import barcode
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter

with open('/MyLocation/tnumfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():    
        issn = barcode.get('issn', line, writer=ImageWriter()) 
        filename = issn.save(line)
```

What's the problem? Well this will generate how ever many barcodes as there are lines in the text document, naming them by the line it's walking through (1321157814)

My problem is ISSN is generating poorly visible barcodes and I cannot transfer from ISSN to EAN, for example, without running into syntax errors and the documentation isnt helping!

[Generated Barcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0jz8.png)

Comment: Can you expand on exactly what your problem is? What do you mean by poorly visible? Could you provide examples?

Comment: The Numbers underneath the barcode are not centered. 
It would look silly if I put this on the tickets I'm trying to sell.

Comment: The generated barcode is in the post now

Comment: What is wrong with that barcode? It looks exactly how I would expect a barcode to look. What exactly do you want it to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like EAN instead of ISSN then you can specify that like so:

```
ean = barcode.get('ean', line, writer=ImageWriter())
```

Comment: This helped for some reason I swear I've tried this a million times, but it worked. 

However it still looks like garbage, let me show you.